# Bounding the optimal solution for a constrained optimization problem

Tags: optimization, proof-writing, numerical-methods, numerical-optimization

In penalty method I would like to prove (*)

> Let $x^*$ is a optimal solution for the below problem

$\min f(x) $

subject to

$g_i(x)<= 0 $  $\forall i=1,..,p$

$h_j(x)=0$ $\forall j=1,..,q$

and $x^*_\mu$ is optimal solution for $f_{a,\mu}(x)=f(x)+\mu p(x)$

\begin{align}
 (*) \qquad \text{ If }\mu_1 <  \mu_2 ~\text{ then }~ f_{a,\mu_1}(x^*_{\mu_1}) \le f_{a,\mu_2}(x^*_{\mu_2} )
\end{align}
We have this statement $$ \forall \mu\ge0: \  \   f_a(x^*_{\mu}) \le f(x^*) $$

Then from above statement I write

$$f_a(x^*_{\mu_1}) \le f(x^*) \le f(x^*_{\mu_2})$$

because $x^*$ is optimal for problem.

Comment: Please check all the edits. It seems even less clear what the proof is and where your problem lies. And yes, the last inequality chain follows from the previous assertions.

Comment: @LutzL hello I edited my question

Comment: Do you have a source link, or a citation reference that one can try on google books? The situation is still unclear. Is $μ$ fixed, is $f_a$ for $x^*_{μ_1}$ the function $f+μp$ or $f+μ_1p$?

Comment: Yes $\mu,\mu_1,\mu_2$ is constant

Comment: That was too much confirmation, thus useless. The question was about the construction of $f_a$, is it always the same or should it be $f_a(x,μ)$?

Comment: $\mu$ is penalty . construction of $f_a$ is related with selection of $\mu$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76631/discussion-between-ken-kavaza-and-lutzl).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A penalty function is positive and satisfies $p(x)=0$ for all $x$ in the admissible set, $g(x)\le 0$ and $h(x)=0$. Then either the optimal solution $x_μ^*$ for $f_{a,μ}=f+μp$ is inside the admissible set and thus $x_μ^*=x^*$. Or you are outside and thus
$$
f(x^*)=f_{a,μ}(x^*)\ge f_{a,μ}(x_μ^*).
$$
If $μ_1<μ_2$ then first by the minimality of $x_{\mu_1}^*$ and then by the non-negativity of $p$
$$
f_{a,μ_1}(x_{\mu_1}^*)\le f_{a,μ_1}(x_{\mu_2}^*)=f_{a,μ_2}(x_{\mu_2}^*)-(μ_2-μ_1)p(x_{\mu_2}^*)\le f_{a,μ_2}(x_{\mu_2}^*).
$$
Which proves (1). However, the last inequality
$$f(x^*)\le f(x_{\mu_2}^*)$$
is only guaranteed to be true if $x_{\mu_2}^*$ is an admissible point, which more often than not will not be the case. If everything is convex, the minimizer $x^*$ will be on the boundary of the admissible set and the $x_{\mu_2}^*$ will lie outside the admissible set and usually have smaller $f$ values.

Example: $f(x)=-x$, $g(x)=x\le 0$, $p(x)=x_+^2=\max(0,x)^2$. Then for $x>0$ $$f_{a,μ}(x)=-x+μx^2=μ\left(x-\frac1{2μ}\right)^2-\frac1{4μ}$$
so that $f_{a,μ}$ has its global minimum at $x_μ^*=\frac1{2μ}$ outside the admissible set with value $f_{a,μ}(x_μ^*)=-\frac1{4μ}<f(x^*)=0$. And also
$$
f(x_μ^*)=-\frac1{2μ}<0=f(x^*).
$$